# How to let greenDAO to create the Database on sdcard ? - Android

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper, greendao

I want to use greenDAO as sqlite DB ORM

but my database should be located on sdcard in a specific folder like `/sdcard/myapp/database.sqlite`

So how to choose the folder of database to be created in using greenDAO ?

Comment: Nice question. Answers helped me alot

Comment: Thank you, im happy it helped you @NaveedAhmad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For quite some time (Android 2.2 I believe) it is possible use `SQLiteOpenHelper` with an absolute path. So for the greendao sample app (only tested with Android 4.4 and 5.0)

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "my_sdcard_dir/deeper_dir/notes-db");
path.getParentFile().mkdirs();

DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, path.getAbsolutePath(), null);
db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
...
```

Alternatively, as the `DaoMaster` only needs the database itself :

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "my_sdcard_dir/deeper_dir/notes-db");
path.getParentFile().mkdirs();

db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(path, null);
DaoMaster.createAllTables(db, true);

daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
...
```

Comment: Thanks man, It helped me alot to solve my problem, I am planning to create a project example on Github for custom Database paths.